# How to hide all other div except one that is clicked?

Tags: javascript

How to hide other and left just one that is click?

I tried something like this, but this doesn't work since all my divs has different ids

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.campingTrips').click(function(e) {
    var image = e.target,
      interval,
      height = 200,
      width = 200,
      z = $(this).css("z-index");
    $(this).css("z-index", z + 10);
    $('#product-container').addClass('disable-click');
    $('.unhidden').not($(this).parent().parent()).addClass('noOpacity');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campingTrips">
  <h1>Camping trips</h1>
</div>

<div id="cityBreaks">
  <h1>City breaks</h1>
</div>

<div id="roadTrips">
  <h1>Road trips</h1>
</div>

<div id="cruises">
  <h1>Cruises</h1>
</div>

<div id="groupTours">
  <h1>Group tours</h1>
</div>

<div id="girlsTrips">
  <h1>Girls’ trips</h1>
</div>
```

I'm using Java, Spring Boot, this is how I'm trying to include jQuery

```
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/index.js}"></script>
```

Edit: NEW CODE

So my html is now like this:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campingTrips" class="clickable"><h1>Camping trips</h1>
</div>

<div id="cityBreaks" class="clickable"><h1>City breaks</h1>
</div>

<div id="roadTrips" class="clickable"><h1>Road trips</h1>
</div>

<div id="cruises" class="clickable"><h1>Cruises</h1>
</div>

<div id="groupTours" class="clickable"><h1>Group tours</h1>
</div>

<div id="girlsTrips" class="clickable"><h1>Girls’ trips</h1>
</div>
```

And js like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('clickable').on('click', function () {
    var current = $(this).attr('id');
    $('clickable:not(#' + current + ')').hide();

})
```

})

Error from inspect console is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at index.js:119:1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide all and then show the clicked one, will have the same effect.

```js
$('.clickable').on('click', (e) => 
{
  // Hide all
  $('.clickable').hide();
  
  // Show this
  $(e.target).closest('div').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campingTrips" class="clickable"><h1>Camping trips</h1>
</div>

<div id="cityBreaks" class="clickable"><h1>City breaks</h1>
</div>

<div id="roadTrips" class="clickable"><h1>Road trips</h1>
</div>

<div id="cruises" class="clickable"><h1>Cruises</h1>
</div>

<div id="groupTours" class="clickable"><h1>Group tours</h1>
</div>

<div id="girlsTrips" class="clickable"><h1>Girls’ trips</h1>
</div>
```

But i strongly suggest to use a specific class for selecting those div elements, or base your code in a parent container.

Comment: Yeah, I know its better, but I need different ID on every div because I consume it later to see which one user click. Anyway, thank you for your help, but that is not good for me, to hide -show - hide all except that one

Comment: Im talking about a class not id. Updated the answer.

Comment: I updated question, can you help me where is problem now since function doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

you can do following:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="campingTrips">
  <h1>Camping trips</h1>
</div>

<div id="cityBreaks">
  <h1>City breaks</h1>
</div>

<div id="roadTrips">
  <h1>Road trips</h1>
</div>

<div id="cruises">
  <h1>Cruises</h1>
</div>

<div id="groupTours">
  <h1>Group tours</h1>
</div>

<div id="girlsTrips">
  <h1>Girls’ trips</h1>
</div>
```

and

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('div').on('click', function() {
        var current = $(this).attr('id');
        $('div:not(#' + current + ')').hide();
        
     })
  })

  </script>
```

It will hide every other div except the one that is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for help, anyway, its seems I also have problem with importing jQuery, I updated my question with imports.

Comment: Its work, but I added classes to my div, can you check again question and see if you can help why my code doesnt work

Comment: Sure!, you are not using a script tag for your jquery script. Include the document.ready() function inside a script tag and it should work.

Comment: But Im using it? This is my sperate file guess i dont need <script> tags cause im in .js file?

Comment: Please make sure to import jquery CDN before importing other .js files. thanks!